# search filter is not working properly in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input

I am trying to filter the data from the table but it is not working properly. on first keyboard click it is showing the whole data from the table. when i click the second letter then it is filtering the data taking the first letter. Also the back keypress is not working.

const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

```
const searchTable = (e: any) => {
let tdata = { columns:tableData.columns,data_source:[]}
setSearchInput(e)
if(e){
  if(tableData && tableData.data_source.length > 0){
    const filterData = tableData.data_source.filter((item:any) => {
      return Object.values(item).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
    })
    tdata.data_source = filterData
    console.log("tata",tdata)
    setTableData(tdata)
  }
}else{
  getTableGoData({});
}
```

};

```
  <Input
        onChange={(e) => searchTable(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Search"
        value = {searchInput}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

useState setter doesn't provide a callback after state update is done like setState does in React class components. In order to replicate the same behaviour, you can make use of the a similar pattern like componentDidUpdate lifecycle method in React class components with useEffect using Hooks.

useEffect hooks takes the second parameter as an array of values which React needs to monitor for change after the render cycle is complete.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let tdata = { columns: tableData.columns, data_source: [] }
    if (searchInput) {
        if (tableData && tableData.data_source.length > 0) {
            const filterData = tableData.data_source.filter((item: any) => {
                return Object.values(item).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
            })
            tdata.data_source = filterData
            console.log("tata", tdata)
            setTableData(tdata)
        }
    } else {
        getTableGoData({});
    }
}, [searchInput])


const searchTable = (e: any) => {

    setSearchInput(e)

}
```

Comment: It worked in forward direction but it is not working in backKeyPress

Comment: <Table
      columns={ columns}
      dataSource={tableData.data_source}
   />